# SQL Server : display distinct list of orders, and indicate which orders contain specific products

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression, outer-join

I have a table that contains a lot of data, but the relevant data in the table looks something like this:

**Orders** table:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| OrderID  | Product   |    Date       |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
|    1     | Apple     |  01/01/2001   |
|    1     | Pear      |  01/01/2001   |
|    1     | Pear      |  01/01/2001   |
|    1     | Orange    |  01/01/2001   |
|    1     | Pineapple |  01/01/2001   |
|    2     | Cherry    |  02/02/2002   |
|    2     | Cherry    |  02/02/2002   |
|    3     | Orange    |  03/03/2003   |
|    3     | Apple     |  03/03/2003   |
|    3     | Cherry    |  03/03/2003   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I'd like a query to return a distinct list of orders, and if the order contains certain products, to indicate as such:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
| OrderID  |   Date    | Apple? | Pear? |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
|    1     |01/01/2001 |    X   |   X   |
|    2     |02/02/2002 |        |       |
|    3     |03/03/2003 |    X   |       |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Here's where I've left off and decided to seek out help:

```
WITH CTEOrder AS
(
   SELECT
       OrderID, Product, Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID ASC) AS OrderRN
   FROM 
       Orders
)
CTEApple as 
(
    SELECT
        OrderID, Product, Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID ASC) AS AppleRN
    FROM 
        Orders
    WHERE 
        Product = 'Apple'
),
CTEPear
(
    SELECT
        OrderID, Product, Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID ASC) AS PearRN
    FROM 
        Orders
    WHERE 
        Product = 'Pear'
)
SELECT
    o.OrderID, o.Product, o.Date,
    co.OrderRN, a.AppleRN, p.PearRN
FROM 
    Orders AS o
OUTER JOIN 
    CTEOrder AS co ON o.OrderID = co.Orderid
OUTER JOIN 
    CTEApple AS a ON o.OrderID = a.OrderID
OUTER JOIN 
    CTEPear AS p ON o.OrderID = p.OrderID
WHERE 
    (co.OrderRN IS NULL AND a.AppleRN IS NULL AND p.PearRN IS NULL
     OR co.OrderRN = 1 AND a.AppleRN IS NULL AND p.PearRN IS NULL
     OR co.OrderRN = 1 AND a.AppleRN = 1 AND p.PearRN IS NULL
     OR co.OrderRN = 1 AND a.AppleRN = 1 AND p.PearRN = 1
     OR co.OrderRN = 1 AND a.AppleRN IS NULL AND p.PearRN = 1
     OR co.OrderRN IS NULL AND a.AppleRN = 1 AND p.PearRN IS NULL
     OR co.OrderRN IS NULL AND a.AppleRN = 1 AND p.PearRN = 1
     OR co.OrderRN IS NULL AND a.AppleRN IS NULL AND p.PearRN = 1)
```

Currently my result set is unwieldy with a significant amount of duplication.

I'm thinking that I am heading in the wrong direction, but I don't know what other tools are available to me within SQL Server to cut up this data the way I need.

Thanks for any guidance!

Here's my result set after Nik Shenoy's guidance:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| OrderID  |    Date   | Apple? | Pear? |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
|    1     | 01/01/2001|    x   |  NULL |
|    1     | 01/01/2001|  NULL  |   x   | 
|    1     | 01/01/2001|  NULL  |   x   |
|    1     | 01/01/2001|  NULL  |  NULL |
|    1     | 01/01/2001|  NULL  |  NULL |
|    2     | 02/02/2002|  NULL  |  NULL |
|    2     | 02/02/2002|  NULL  |  NULL |
|    3     | 03/03/2003|  NULL  |  NULL |
|    3     | 03/03/2003|    x   |  NULL |
|    3     | 03/03/2003|  NULL  |  NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

What is my next step to have only 1 row per Order:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
| OrderID  |   Date    | Apple? | Pear? |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
|    1     |01/01/2001 |    X   |   X   |
|    2     |02/02/2002 |        |       |
|    3     |03/03/2003 |    X   |       |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: I am impressed at your attempt for what looks like a simple problem.

Comment: The term is 'pivot'. But if you clearly & concisely stated what you are doing in terms of values & columns & column names & googled that you would hit lots of pivot questions & answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know all the products in advance, you can use the Transact-SQL PIVOT relational operator to cross-tabulate the data by product. If you use MAX or COUNT, you can just transform non-NULL or non-ZERO output to an 'x'

```
SELECT
    PivotData.OrderID
,   PivotData.OrderDate
,   CASE WHEN PivotData.Apple IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS [Apple?]
,   CASE WHEN PivotData.Pear IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS [Pear?]
,   CASE WHEN PivotData.Orange IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS [Orange?]
,   CASE WHEN PivotData.Pineapple IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS     [Pineapple?]
,   CASE WHEN PivotData.Cherry IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS [Cherry?]
FROM
    (SELECT OrderID, Product, OrderDate) AS [Order]
PIVOT   (MAX(Product) FOR Product IN ( [Apple], [Pear], [Orange], [Pineapple], [Cherry] )) AS PivotData
```

Comment: Thanks Nik Shenoy, this has me almost there! The result set now lists all of the orders, the Pear?/Apple? columns have an 'X' in the appropriate place, but I'm left with all the nulls as well. What should my next step me to retieve only 1 row per order?

Comment: I added a subquery. If the source table for the PIVOT operator contains other fields, you may see row duplication. If you cut down the source table, that should go away and you should see one row per order/date combination.

Comment: Maybe I am getting a different result as my source table is actually the product of a join? Here's my query after your guidance:

SELECT
 OrderID
 ,Date
 ,[Apple?]
 ,[Pear?]
FROM 
 (
 Select
  o.OrderID
  ,o.Date
  ,o.ProductID
  .p.ProductName
 From Orders as O
 JOIN Product as p
         on o.ProductID = p.ProductID
 ) 
as SourceTable
Pivot
 (
 MAX(ProductName) FOR ProductName in ([Apple?], [Pear?])
 ) as PivotData

Comment: You need to get rid of the 'o.ProductID' in your subquery. That will be unique per product, so the pivot won't be able to aggregate by only OrderID and Date.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select o.orderid, date,
       max(case when product = 'Apple' then 'X' end) as IsApple,
       max(case when product = 'Pear' then 'X' end) as IsPear
from orders o
group by o.orderid, date;
```